# How to override core functionality of drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I am looking for a CMS tool and looks like the top ones (with highest market share) are mostly PHP based.

So started building a POC using Drupal as it can be tweaked extensively.

I am facing few issues,

1. Created articles using Drupal admin panel and when content is populated in the view there are many structural html tags(div,span) wrapped around the actual content. Is there a possibility if we can override and remove these changes. Tried overriding using templates but it is deeply nested and it seems we have to override many template files. Also looking to override at controller level if possible
2. For each block on the UI is it possible to have a separate controller kind of thing which fetches data from database and binds to the UI.

Any guidance to sample code / good documentation will be helpful? and also is it good to use Drupal as headless or should we consider other headless CMS like Strapi/Ghost.

Comment: Too many questions in one post, asking for recommendations too. So it's off-topic on several counts. Please ask a single, focused question about a specific issue, and make sure it's on-topic and answerable, and demonstrates some prior research/effort. See also [ask], [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and the [tour]. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.